# Is there any move that cures the enemy pokemon's status problems?

Tags: pokemon-heart-gold-soul-silver

I am currently engaged in a desperate struggle to capture the roaming legendary beasts. I have my sights set on Entei at the moment, having brought it down to 1 HP and paralyzed it. Sadly, it is still infuriatingly difficult to catch.

This was all done before I realized that applying the "sleep" condition is preferable than applying the "paralysis" condition for the purpose of capturing pokemon.

Seeing how you cannot afflict a pokemon with two status ailments, I would like to cure the Entei's paralysis so that I could make it sleep instead. Is there any move that will allow me to do this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are at least three ways. Unfortunately, none will work on your scenario.

**Fling**, when used with a corresponding status healing berry, should recover the status condition. However, it counts as a 10 Power attack prior to causing the effect, so you would not even be able to throw a Sitrus berry for healing before you would kill something at 1 HP.

**Trick** and all of its derivatives can be used to swap a status healing berry onto the target. None of the Legendary Beasts have held items to my knowledge, though, so this won't work.

Finally, the moves **Wake-Up Slap** and **Smelling Salts** will cure Sleep and Paralysis respectively. But not only do they do damage, they do *double* damage to such an afflicted Pokémon. So like Fling, not viable.

Comment: Most? That looks like all, to me.

Comment: @Aubergine It's a leftover from when I wasn't sure about Fling. I'll fix that.

Comment: The Fling/Smelling Salts causing damage problem can be worked around if you heal the enemy first. You can use Pain Split, or get lucky with Present(20% chance). Since Present has an 80% chance to KO the enemy if it has 1HP, I'd go with Pain Split.

Answer (score 6):

Kill it. No, really. After you defeat the Elite Four again, any roaming legendaries you knocked out will return to the the Brass Tower, at full health and status effects.

As for capturing Entei, beware that roaming legendaries can flee even when asleep. You need to use Mean Look or Block, or a Pokemon with the ability Shadow Tag or Arena Trap. This will give you more than one round to throw Pokeballs, and greatly increase your chance of capturing Entei.

Entei can still escape using Roar, but blocking this while keeping a no-fleeing effect in play involves a lot of specialist breeding work. The easiest is to level an Eevee to L36 to learn Baton Pass, evolve it to an Umbreon and level it to L57 to learn Mean Look. Use this to trap Entei and Baton Pass out to something with the ability Soundproof or Suction Cups or the move Ingrain, any of which will block Roar. Many such Pokemon can learn a sleep or paralysis move by breeding or level.

Both Entei and Raikou are fast enough to benefit from Fast Ball, which gives a 4x catch rate, better than an Ultra Ball. There is no better Pokeball for Entei or Raikou.

Comment: "Can flee even when asleep" http://www.awkwardzombie.com/index.php?page=0&comic=053110 http://stephi-jk.deviantart.com/art/Fast-Asleep-Entei-162032873

Answer (score 2):

Use **Manaphy** to **Skill Swap** its Hydration ability to the target pokemon. Since you only have one turn, you may have to do this on route 33 where it rains naturally.

Unfortunately, no pokemon with Leaf Guard or Shed Skin (my first idea) will learn Skill Swap.

Comment: My apologies, I must have mixed that ability with something else that simply heals a pokemon (thus allowing me to remove the paralysis using one of the other methods mentioned above). I'll go ahead and kill my previous comment. I won't argue with your, however, that a Manaphy is a pretty problematic prerequisite.

Answer (score 0):

Having the paralyze condition instead of sleep is not a problem at all, especially when its HP is down to 1. Furthermore, pokemon wake up from sleep, whereas they do not get cured of paralysis (unless they have the move Refresh).

Paralyze is 1.5x instead of 2x for sleep, but using a Dusk Ball (3.5x) or Quick Ball (4x) or Timer Ball (4x) is more effective than both if used at the right time. You'll catch it eventually!

Side note: **Haze** used to cure the opponent's status ailment in the first two generations, but this has since been removed for some reason.

Comment: While true, seeing how the Entei constantly tries to flee, sleep could give me several turns to catch it, instead of just one. Also, you'd be surprised how many quick balls I have wasted in my attempts already, so I'm really trying to up my chances.

Comment: They still flee while asleep...

Comment: @Aubergine: Aren't you using Mean Look or similar move that prevents fleeing? If not then half the time your sleep move won't work and the pokemon will flee anyway. So there is barely any difference.

Answer (score 0):

Kill it. After you beat the Elite Four again, they will reappear at full health and everything. Or! Hunt for him at night or set your DS clock to night and then throw dusk balls at it. Use mean look or something. Paralysis reduces the speed and dusk have a 4x catch multiplier when thrown at night. I caught all legendaries using a Dusk Ball. Try it! you get it at the pokemart.

Answer (score -1):

Use Present. It might affect it but there is a 10% chance it will cure Entei. You can turn off without saving and try it again, though.

Comment: Does [present](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Present_(move)) actually cure status effects? Bulbapedia doesn't say so

Comment: A good question... Present was actually mentioned in one of the higher rated comments for the accepted answer as something to bolster my chances of not killing Entei with other moves, moves that could solve my predicament if they did not cause damage. I don't see how present is a direct solution to the problem.